Absolute profinite rigidity of free nilpotent groups
Do you know of a reference for the following statement (taken from Martin Bridson's essay [1])?

The free nilpotent group of fixed class on a fixed number of generators is profinitely rigid.

It is clear that any residually finite group sharing profinite completion with a free nilpotent group has to satisfy the same group law and thus be nilpotent of the same class, but I don't know why it is distinguished from the other nilpotent groups in this class.
[1] Bridson, Martin R. "Profinite Rigidity and Free Groups." Mathematics Going Forward: Collected Mathematical Brushstrokes.
